# How to increase size logo in quarto reveal.js presentation

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

In my quarto reveal.js presentation, I added a logo bottom left in the slide template by placing this in the yaml:

```
format: 
  revealjs:
    logo: mylogo.png
```

The logo is displayed very small. Anyone a suggestion on how to increase the size? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

logo image in the quarto revealjs has the class `slide-logo`. So to increase the size, you just need to apply the following CSS rules to this `.slide-logo` selector.

```
---
title: "Increasing Logo size"
format: 
  revealjs:
    logo: image.png
    css: logo.css
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations, see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.
```

**logo.css**

```
.reveal .slide-logo {
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  max-width: unset !important;
  max-height: unset !important;
}
```

---

[image: a big logo on the bottom-left corner]

---

Change the value of CSS properties `height` and `width` as you need, and **Do not forget the `!important`**

**EDIT:**

- Depending on how `max-height`, `height`, and the size of the image file correspond, the logo moves upwards. To avoid this, try using `max-height` only.